# C++ Destructor error when using vectors

Tags: c++, vector

I have a little project of mine. I'm a beginner C++ developer, so I still try to stay away from pointer as far as I can. The problem is, I have several structs.

- World - this handle the screen
- Player- this stores everything for one user
- Unit - the values for an unit, one user will have multiple units

The code:

```
struct Unit
{
public:
Unit(char* name, int imgId, bool left)
{
    Burning = 0;
    Slowed = 0;
    Area = 0;
    this->Name = string(name);
    ImgId = imgId;
    LeftTeam = left;
}

Unit()
{
    Burning = 0;
    Slowed = 0;
    Area = 0;
}

Unit(char* name, bool left, int unitCount)
{
    Burning = 0;
    Slowed = 0;
    this->Name = name;
    LeftTeam = left;
    SetStats();
}


void Update()
{
    if (Health > 0)
    {
        if (Slowed > 0)
        {
            X += (Speed * FreezeLost);
            Slowed--;
        }
        else
            X += Speed;


    }
    if (Burning > 0)
    {
        Health -= BurningDamage;
        Burning--;
    }
}

int GetX()
{
    return X;
}

int GetY()
{
    return Y;
}

int GetArea()
{
    return Area;
}

void Spawn(int x, int y)
{
    X = x;
    Y = y;
}

void Burn()
{
    Burning = BurningRound;
}

void Freeze()
{
    Slowed = FreezeRound;
}

void Damage(int dmg)
{
    Health -= dmg;
    if (Speed / 5 == 0)
        X -= Speed/abs(Speed);
    else
        X -= Speed / 5;
}

int GetDamage()
{
    return Attack;
}

string GetName()
{
    return Name;
}

string GetDescribtion()
{
    return Describtion;
}

int GetImgId()
{
    return ImgId;
}

~Unit()
{}
private:
int X;
int Y;
string Name;
int Health;
int Speed;
int Attack;
bool Ranged;
int Burning;
int Slowed;
bool LeftTeam;
int ImgId;
string Describtion;

void SetStats()
{
    if (strcmp(Name.c_str(), "h") == 0)
    {
        Health = 100;
        Speed = 5;
        Attack = 15;
        Ranged = true;
        ImgId = LeftTeam ? 0 : unitCount;
        Describtion = "asd;
    }
    else if (strcmp(Name.c_str(), "g") == 0)
    {
        Health = 200;
        Speed = 3;
        Attack = 3;
        Ranged = true;
        ImgId = LeftTeam ? 1 : unitCount + 1;
        Describtion = "asd";
    }
    else if (strcmp(Name.c_str(), "f") == 0)
    {
        Health = 200;
        Speed = 3;
        Attack = 3;
        Ranged = true;
        ImgId = LeftTeam ? 2 : unitCount + 2;
        Describtion = "asd";
    }
    else if (strcmp(Name.c_str(), "e") == 0)
    {
        Health = 1000;
        Speed = 1;
        Attack = 100;
        Ranged = false;
        ImgId = LeftTeam ? 3 : unitCount + 3;
        Describtion = "asd";
    }
    else if (strcmp(Name.c_str(), "d") == 0)
    {
        Health = 250;
        Speed = 4;
        Attack = 50;
        Ranged = true;
        ImgId = LeftTeam ? 4 : unitCount + 4;
        Describtion = "asd";
    }
    else if (strcmp(Name.c_str(), "c") == 0)
    {
        Health = 300;
        Speed = 3;
        Attack = 30;
        Ranged = false;
        ImgId = LeftTeam ? 5 : unitCount + 5;
        Describtion = "asd";
    }
    else if (strcmp(Name.c_str(), "b") == 0)
    {
        Health = 75;
        Speed = 10;
        Attack = 10;
        Ranged = false;
        ImgId = LeftTeam ? 6 : unitCount + 6;
        Describtion = "asd";
    }
    else if (strcmp(Name.c_str(), "a") == 0)
    {
        Health = 150;
        Speed = 5;
        Attack = 25;
        Ranged = false;
        ImgId = LeftTeam ? 7 : unitCount + 7;
        Describtion = "asd";
    }
}
};

struct Player
{
private:
Unit* aviableUnits;
Button* gameButtons;
Button* mainMenuButtons;
bool leftPlayer;
vector<Unit> units;
int winningPercent;
int usedUnits;
int* Timers;

bool inGame;
LoadingBar* UnitCooldown;

int ActiveButtonCount()
{
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < unitCount; i++)
    {
        if(mainMenuButtons[i].IsSelected())
        {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
public:
Player()
{
    aviableUnits = new Unit[0];
    leftPlayer = false;
    winningPercent = 0;
    inGame = false;
    usedUnits = 0;



}

Player(bool isLeftPlayer)
{
    aviableUnits = new Unit[MaxUnitTypes];
    leftPlayer = isLeftPlayer;
    winningPercent = 50;
    inGame = false;
    usedUnits = 0;
}

void SetMainMenuButtons(Button* mainMenuButtons)
{
    this->mainMenuButtons = mainMenuButtons;
    mainMenuButtons[unitCount].CursorEnter();
}

Button* GetMainMenuButtons()
{
    return mainMenuButtons;
}

Button* GetGameButtons()
{
    return gameButtons;
}

int GetUsedUnits()
{
    return usedUnits;
}

void AddUnit(char* name, bool left, int X, int Y)
{
    units.push_back(Unit(name, left, unitCount));
    units[units.size() - 1].Spawn(X, Y);
}

void EnterGameMode()
{
    Colour c1 = Colour(240, 240, 240);
    Colour c2 = Colour(102, 53, 175);
    Colour c3 = Colour(230, 255, 0);
    Colour c4 = Colour(255, 255, 255);

    usedUnits = ActiveButtonCount();
    Unit temp;
    int currentButton = 0;
    gameButtons = new Button[usedUnits];
    UnitCooldown = new LoadingBar[usedUnits];
    Timers = new int[usedUnits];

    for (int i = 0; i < unitCount; i++)
    {
        if(mainMenuButtons[i].IsSelected())
        {
            if(leftPlayer)
            {
                gameButtons[currentButton] = Button(10 + 25 * currentButton, 40, 10, c1, c2, c3, c4, mainMenuButtons[i].GetTextAsChar());
                UnitCooldown[currentButton] = LoadingBar(true, 25 * currentButton, 60, 20 + 25 * currentButton, 100, 1, Colour(), Colour(0, 255, 0), Colour(255, 0, 0));
            }
            else
            {
                gameButtons[currentButton] = Button(WindowX - 10 - 25 * currentButton, 40, 10, c1, c2, c3, c4,mainMenuButtons[i].GetTextAsChar());
                UnitCooldown[currentButton] = LoadingBar(true, WindowX - (25 * (currentButton + 1) - 20), 60, WindowX - (25 * (currentButton + 1)), 100, 1, Colour(), Colour(0, 255, 0), Colour(255, 0, 0));
            }

            UnitCooldown[currentButton].EditMaximumValue(500);
            gameButtons[currentButton].TextDisplay(false);

            for (int k = 0; k < unitCount; k++)
            {
                if(strcmp(unitNames[k], mainMenuButtons[i].GetTextAsChar()) == 0)
                    Timers[currentButton] = loadingTimes[k];
            }

            currentButton++;
        }
    }
    gameButtons[0].CursorEnter();

    inGame = true;
}

vector<Unit>& GetUnits()
{
    return units;
}

Button& currentSelectedButton()
{
    if (inGame)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < usedUnits - 1; i++)
        {
            if (gameButtons[i].IsActive())
            {
                return gameButtons[i];
            }
        }
    }

    if (!inGame)
        cout << "Error";

    return gameButtons[0];
}

void PrintGameButtons()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < usedUnits; i++)
    {
        gameButtons[i].GetButton();
        UnitCooldown[i].DrawLoadingBar();
    }
}

void UpdateCooldown()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < usedUnits; i++)
    {
        UnitCooldown[i].UpdateLoadingBarStatus(Timers[i]);
    }
}

int GetUnitCount()
{
    return unitCount;
}

bool IsCooldownComplete(int where)
{
    if (where <= usedUnits && UnitCooldown[where].IsReady())
    {
        UnitCooldown[where].UpdateLoadingBarStatus(-UnitCooldown[where].GetMaximumValue());
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}
};
struct World
{
private:
LoadingBar GameWinningState;
Player* player1;
Player* player2;

int leftArrowY;
int rightArrowY;

int CurrentlyActiveButton(Button b[], int lenght)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < lenght; i++)
    {
        if (b[i].IsActive())
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

Unit createUnit(bool left, char* name)
{
    if(left)
    {
        player1->AddUnit(name, left, 5, leftArrowY - 20);
    }
}
public:
World(Player& player1, Player& player2)
{
    GameWinningState = LoadingBar(false, 5, WindowY - 5, WindowX - 5, WindowY - 20, 1, Colour(), Colour(0, 0, 255), Colour(255, 255, 0));
    GameWinningState.UpdateLoadingBarStatus(50);
    this->player1 = &player1;
    this->player2 = &player2;
    leftArrowY = 120;
    rightArrowY = 120;
}

void DrawWorld()
{
    gout << move_to(10, 20) << color(0, 0, 0) << text(player1->currentSelectedButton().GetTextAsChar());
    gout << move_to(WindowX - gout.twidth(player2->currentSelectedButton().GetTextAsString()) - 5, 20) << text(player2->currentSelectedButton().GetTextAsChar());
    player1->PrintGameButtons();
    player2->PrintGameButtons();
    //units
    DrawArrow(leftArrowY, rightArrowY);
    //end of units
    GameWinningState.DrawLoadingBar();

    player1->UpdateCooldown();
    player2->UpdateCooldown();

}
void UpdateWorld(event ev)
{

    int max1 = player1->GetUsedUnits();
    int max2 = player2->GetUsedUnits();

    Button* player1Buttons = player1->GetGameButtons();
    Button* player2Buttons = player2->GetGameButtons();

    int active1 = CurrentlyActiveButton(player1Buttons, max1);
    int active2 = CurrentlyActiveButton(player2Buttons, max2);

    if (ev.keycode == 97 && active1 > 0)
    {
        player1Buttons[active1].CursorLeave();
        player1Buttons[active1 - 1].CursorEnter();
    }
    else if (ev.keycode == 100 && active1 != -1 && active1 < max1 - 1)
    {
        player1Buttons[active1].CursorLeave();
        player1Buttons[active1 + 1].CursorEnter();
    }
    else if (ev.keycode == key_right && active2 > 0)
    {
        player2Buttons[active2].CursorLeave();
        player2Buttons[active2 - 1].CursorEnter();
    }
    else if (ev.keycode == key_left && active2 != -1 && active2 < max2 - 1)
    {
        player2Buttons[active2].CursorLeave();
        player2Buttons[active2 + 1].CursorEnter();
    }
    else if (ev.keycode == 119 && leftArrowY > 120)
    {
        leftArrowY -= 50;
    }
    else if (ev.keycode == 115 && leftArrowY < 520)
    {
        leftArrowY += 50;
    }
    else if (ev.keycode == key_up && rightArrowY > 120)
    {
        rightArrowY -= 50;
    }
    else if (ev.keycode == key_down && rightArrowY < 520)
    {
        rightArrowY += 50;
    }
    else if(ev.keycode == key_space)
    {
        if (player1->IsCooldownComplete(active1))
            createUnit(true, player1Buttons[active1].GetTextAsChar());
    }
    else if(ev.keycode == 48)
    {
        if (player2->IsCooldownComplete(active2))
            createUnit(false, player2Buttons[active2].GetTextAsChar());
    }
}
};
```

Everything has worked fine, but when I tried, to use the *createUnit* function, I've got this error in the debugger:

```
#0 0x463b17 std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string() () (??:??)
#1 0x4331d2 Unit::~Unit(this=0x6cfce0, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) ---\main.cpp:568)
#2 0x433b10 World::UpdateWorld(this=0x6cfe74, ev=...) (---\main.cpp:949)
#3 0x402a55 Update(player1=..., player2=..., world=..., ev=..., InGame=@0x6cfeeb: true) (---\main.cpp:1165)
#4 0x401551 main() (---\main.cpp:1014)
```

First, I tought it misses the destructor, so I have created an empty one, but it didn't solved my problem. I never encountered this type of error before, and I don't fully understand, what's the problem?

Comment: `The problem is, I have several structs.` I don't see a problem with that.

Comment: " I still try to stay away from pointer as far as I can." Doesn't look like you did. Where's `unique_ptr` and `vector`?

Comment: availableUnits looks funny

Comment: Please mark the locations from the call stack in your question

Comment: Why do you use `std::vector` in one place like here: `vector<Unit> units;`, and do not use it in other places where you could be using it, like here: `Timers = new int[usedUnits];`?